# Multiple programs updating the same database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have a website developed with ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework Code First and SQL Server.
The website has entities that each have a history of statuses that we defined (NEW, PACKED, SHIPPED etc.)
The DB contains a table in which a completely separate system inserts parcel tracking data.
I have to read this data tracking data and, following certain business rules, add to the existing status history of my entities.

The best way I can think of is to write an independent Windows service to poll the tracking data every so often and update my entity statuses from that. However, that makes me concerned about DB concurrency issues.

Please could someone advise me on the best strategy for this scenario?
Many thanks

Comment: [Transactions, transactions, transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)... optimistic concurrency -- which is well supported in EF -- is also nice, but not suited in all cases (and still requires transactions internally to ensure [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)). Everyone must *correctly participate* at some level.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this doesn't address the issue of responding to new tracking data from the other system. Is a Windows service the way to go? How about a database trigger? I assume it would be nasty to check it on every postback by using my BaseController?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do it. It also depends on the response time you need. If you need to update your system as soon as the tracking system updates the record then a trigger is the preferred way. Alternative way is to schedule a [job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx) which will run every 15/30mins and sync the 2 systems.

As for the concurrency issue you can use a concurrency token field. Entity framework has [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx) for this.

Comment: Fortunately, the business rules are relatively simple and I was able to implement this with a database trigger and it seems to be working well. I'm sure a more complex scenario would necessitate some C# code but I'm still unclear whether a Windows service would be the best way. Anyway, my immediate problem is solved but it would be handy info for future reference... Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @Mark if that windows service is just for data manipulation then you can implement it as a SP and create a database job for that. That would be more efficient.